# Modular functions of weight 0 and the J invariant

Tags: modular-forms

I have seen the following theorem in several places, but have yet to find a clear proof:

Any weight 0 modular function can be expressed as a rational function of the J invariant

I would love to try and figure how to prove this on my own, however I don't know where to start. I believe I have seen somewhere that the leading term of $\frac{1}{q}$ is the key as it allows polynomials of J to include poles of any order at $q=0$, but I don't know what else to do. Any help or links to resources appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is the theory of compact Riemann surfaces.

---

The field of functions meromorphic on the first modular curve $X(1) =SL_2(Z) \setminus\mathcal{H}\cup i\infty$ is $\Bbb{C}(j)$ because $j$ has only one simple pole at $i\infty$

whence for $f$ meromorphic on $X(1)$ $$g(z) = f(z) \prod_{p \in SL_2(Z) \setminus H} (j(z)-j(p))^{\max(0,-v_p(f))}$$
is meromorphic on $X(1)$ with no poles on $\mathcal{H}$.

Let $g_0 = g, e = \max(0,-v_{i\infty}(g_l)), c_l = \lim_{z \to i\infty} e^{2i \pi (e-l) z} g_l(z), g_{l+1} = g_l -c_l j^{e-l} $ then $g_e$ 
is holomorphic on  $X(1)$ thus (maximum modulus principle) it is constant $= g_e(i\infty)$ and $$f(z) = \frac{g_e(i\infty)+\sum_{l=0}^{e-1} c_l j(z)^{e-l}}{\prod_{p \in SL_2(Z) \setminus H} (j(z)-j(p))^{\max(0,-v_p(f))}}$$

Comment: X(1) is the fundamental region of the modular group, correct? I tried to stay away from topology so I never really paid too much attention to modular curves

Comment: At your level you need to make clear that $j$ is meromorphic on $X(1)$ while $e^j$ is not, nor do $e^{2i \pi z}$. $X(1)$ is a compact Riemann surface, it has no boundary, it is the minimal data you need to make sense to "the field of functions meromorphic on $X(1)$"

Comment: I think I understand, but I don't really see a need to even introduce X(1)… why can't we just see that g(z) is meromorphic on H, then kill the poles at $i\infty$ with $\Delta^m$-this would then be in $M_{12m} (\Gamma)$, so it would be expressable as a sum of Eisenstein series, which when divided by $\Delta^m$ would be expressable as j?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Modular forms are holomorphic on $H$ but not on $X(1)$. We need $X(1)$ because only there holomorphic functions are constant.

Comment: what's the distinction between X(1) and $H$? Is it that X(1) has a point at $i\infty$ while H technically doesn't? And can you clarify if my comment about X(1) being the fundamental domain is correct because I don't have a lot of intuition on this. Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I doubt you made useful researches. $X(1) = \{ SL_2(Z) z, z \in H \cup i \infty\}$ it has the structure of a compact Riemann surface : $f$ is meromorphic on $X(1)$ iff it is meromorphic on $H= \{z,\Im(z) > 0\}$, if it is $SL_2(Z)$ invariant, and $f( \frac{\log z}{2i \pi z})$ is meromorphic at $0$. This is in every text on Riemann surfaces, on modular forms, on $j$.

Comment: I spent hours trying to find a clear reference but the only thing I'm really able to find are texts from Stanford and Harvard, which are really hard to understand especially when you're in high school and have had no sort of introduction on topology. I was just looking for a solid clarification of what I thought, and now I understand. I probably don't understand fully, but all I really care about is having a general understanding of things. Thank you